# @SpringBootTest loads unrequired Bean when making IT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm making some Integration Tests for my app and I'm encountering this problem I can't see how to solve.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.13 + Spring Data Neo4J 6.1.9

FYI, I deleted the Application default test that comes bundled when you create a project through Spring Initializr, and under /src/test/resources I have a .yml file named application.yml

My IT class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ClientIT {

    @Autowired
    private ClientServiceImpl service;

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository repository;

    @Test
    void someTest() {
       //Given
       //When
       //Then
    }
}
```

But when I run this test I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

And this is the cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided database selection provider differs from the ReactiveNeo4jClient's one.
```

The thing is I don't use SDN's Reactive features at all in my project. I don't even understand why Spring tries to load it. I've created an Issue under the Spring Data Neo4j GitHub repository (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2488) but they could only tell me that ReactiveNeo4jDataAutoConfiguration gets automatically included if there's a Driver or Flux class in the classpath which I don't have.

I've been debugging the Spring internals while booting up the Application after JUnit Jupiter methods to no success.

What I could see is that at some point after JUnit Jupiter tests preparation/initialization, "reactiveNeo4jTemplate" gets injected into DefaultListableBeanFactory's beanDefinitionNames variable.

I've tried many combinations of different annotations intended to be used when making Integration Tests but the one time it worked was after I explicitly excluded ReactiveNeo4jDataAutoConfiguration class through

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=ReactiveNeo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class)
```

What I've always seen in some blogposts is that by using @SpringBootTest I shouldn't worry about this kind of problem but it looks like I need to add that annotation every time I want to make a new IT test.

My Integration Tests basically consist of bootstrapping the application + web server (tomcat) along with an embedded Neo4J instance and after that, making requests to check everything works as it should. Do I really need to worry about all of this just to make these simple tests?

Thank you

References:

[How do I set up a Spring Data Neo4j integration test with JUnit 5 (in Kotlin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60557184/how-do-i-set-up-a-spring-data-neo4j-integration-test-with-junit-5-in-kotlin)

[SprintBootTest - create only necessary beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317227/sprintboottest-create-only-necessary-beans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after finding what is causing this error:

In the linked Github Issue, one of the developers says having `Flux.class` in the classpath forces SDN to instantiate `Neo4jReactiveDataAutoConfiguration` which is what is causing the other reactive beans to instantiate.

Apparently, `neo4j-harness` brings `io.projectreactor` (where `Flux.class` belongs) as an indirect dependency through `neo4j-fabric` which is the root of our problems.

The Spring Data Neo4j will be fixing this issue in a patch later this week.